# Automatic moving Input

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to have the Input someone puts into the Cell "M19" move to "Z1" and if that Cell is full move it to "Z2" and so on so forth.

Currently my code accurately moves the first and second Input into "M19" into "Z1" and "Z2" but afterwards just stops doing anything.

```
function myFunction()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var vZPos = "M19";
  var zZPos = "Z1";
  var vonZelle = ss.getRange(vZPos); //InputCell
  var zuZelle = ss.getRange(zZPos);  //FirstOutputCell
  var i = 0;
  var c = 2; 
  var cTos = c.toString();
  var naechsteZuZelle = zZPos.replace("1", cTos);  
  var naechsteZuZelleRange = ss.getRange(naechsteZuZelle);  //ChangingOutputCell

  do
  {
    if (zuZelle.isBlank() == true && c == 2)
    {
      vonZelle.moveTo(zuZelle);
      i++;
    }
    else 
    {
      if (naechsteZuZelleRange.isBlank() == true)
      {      
        vonZelle.moveTo(naechsteZuZelleRange);
        i++;
      }
      else
      {
        c++;
      }
    }
  }
  while (i == 0);
}
```

Since I'm not that skilled at coding I've kinda hit a brick wall on how to go on about doing things, I would aprreciate any help and/or explanations on how to solve my Problem.

P.S. Since I'm coding in German some of the Variable names might seem weird, if there are any questions I'll do my best to translate/elaborate on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
  else
  {
    c++;
  }
```

To:

```
else
  {
   c++;
   cTos = c.toString();
   var naechsteZuZelle = zZPos.replace("1", cTos);  
   var naechsteZuZelleRange = ss.getRange(naechsteZuZelle)
  }
```

It was not in your loop.

Comment: Ah I see Thank you for the Answer, greatly appreciate it! :D